# Execute a conditional only if another conditional has already been executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to send two events to Google Analytics when two `if` conditionals are met when the user resizes the browser window.

These events are: **Mobile browser width** and **Non-mobile browser width**

For this, I am using the following code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if(window.outerWidth >= 800){
     gtag('event', 'Mobile browser width', {'event_category': 'BrowserWidth'});
   
   if(window.outerWidth <= 801){
   gtag('event', 'Non-mobile browser width', {'event_category': 'BrowserWidth'});
   }
  });
```

But I am facing a problem: due to the nature of `.resize ()`, these conditionals are met for each resized pixel, which consequently causes the `gtag ()` event to be fired numerous times, and that is not what I expected to happen.

What I want is for the **Mobile browser width** event to be triggered once, and to be triggered again only if the **Non-mobile browser width** event has already been triggered.

Here is an example of the order in which these events should be sent to Google Analytics:

1st `resize()` activation: Is `window.outerWidth <= 801`? **True!**
Then dispatch **Mobile browser width** event

2nd `resize()` activation: Is `window.outerWidth <= 801`? **True!**
Then do not dispatch **Mobile browser width** event

3rd `resize()` activation: Is `window.outerWidth >= 800`? **True!**
Then dispatch **Non-mobile browser width** event

4th `resize()` activation: Is `window.outerWidth <= 801`? **True!**
Then dispatch **Mobile browser width** event

5th `resize()` activation: Is `window.outerWidth >= 800`? **True!**
Then dispatch **Non-mobile browser width** event

... and so on.

This is the most didactic way I found to exemplify how I want events to be sent to Google Analytics. Could someone help me on how to adapt my code to respect these rules?

Comment: I will just point out that for a window width of `800` or `801` then both conditions are true... Now what?

Comment: Anyway, the answer is to maintain an `isMobile` boolean and only send the `gtag` if the state changes.

Comment: I don´t understand the question

Comment: the "maintain a boolean approach" seems brittle and non-reusable. A better approach is debounce, IMHO.  :) But yes, now that I read close I don't fully understand the question maybe.  What problem are you trying to solve in terms of firing the event twice?

Comment: @E.Maggini I thought that at first as well, but if you resize from 810->820 wait then 820->830 you get two events (regardless of any skipped between) and OP appears to want only 1 as it's already fired the first

Comment: OK...I will update my answer to use this logic....but the function itself should not trigger on every pixel change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement some kind of [debounce function](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

NOTE: this have been updated to include part of @rob bailey's answer.
[Here is a working jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/4m5p1zf8/2/)

The advantage to this approach is you really only want to fire the function once....not multiple times. That's a waste of cycles and can lead to poor performance.

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

```
var isMobileEvent = false;

var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
    if (window.outerWidth > 800 && !isMobileEvent) {
    gtag('event', 'Mobile browser width', { event_category: 'BrowserWidth' });
    isMobileEvent = true;
  }
  if (window.outerWidth < 801 && isMobileEvent) {
    gtag('event', 'Non-mobile browser width', {
      event_category: 'BrowserWidth',
    });
    isMobileEvent = false;
  }
}, 250);

window.addEventListener('resize', myEfficientFn);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could store a reference to the previously fired event then check that variable before firing a new event. Something like:

```
let latestEvent;
$(window).resize(function () {
  if (window.outerWidth >= 800 && latestEvent !== 'mobile') {
    gtag('event', 'Mobile browser width', { event_category: 'BrowserWidth' });
    latestEvent = 'mobile';
  }
  if (window.outerWidth <= 801 && latestEvent !== 'desktop') {
    gtag('event', 'Non-mobile browser width', {
      event_category: 'BrowserWidth',
    });
    latestEvent = 'desktop';
  }
});
```

Or a boolean for `isMobile` would also work.